# View Expansion and Removing "dead variables"

Tags: postgresql, view

I have a large set of interwoven views in Postgres that sometimes are make inefficient use of other views.

For example,

```
CREATE VIEW C AS
SELECT A.a, B.b
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B on A.id = B.id
```

Then,

```
SELECT C.a
FROM C
GROUP BY C.a
```

It's more complicated, but the idea is that the second query doesn't make use of the JOIN from the VIEW. In the EXPLAIN, this is not optimized away by Postgres.

I'm looking for an **automated** way to "expand" the second query to something like,

```
SELECT C.a
FROM (
  SELECT A.a, B.b
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B on A.id = B.id
) C
GROUP BY C.a
```

So I could then easily see the optimization and make the change my hand.

Comment: Not using the join would give different results. No wonder PostgreSQL keeps it.

Comment: BTW: don't create views using other views. Optimizers tend to have problems finding the best path.

Comment: You are right. I would have removed the COUNT.